# Slow display rendering (not games or video), Windows 8.1, SSD, Intel i7, NVIDIA GTS 240

Tags: windows-8, display, multiple-monitors

I'm experiencing very slow display rendering of static windows on a high spec Windows 8.1 desktop with dual monitors. Not talking about games or video. Just static windows. Examples are moving an Excel 2013 window from one monitor to another and maximizing the FileZilla window.

My specs are as follows:

- Intel i7
- SSD as system (and only) drive
- 8Gb RAM
- NVIDIA GTS 240 display adaptor
- No antivirus software except the Windows Defender that ships with Win 8.1

I have tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- check for malware bot using resource monitor to see network activity. Found nothing unusual
- check for disk thrashing using resource monitor. Found none.
- check for CPU redlining using resource monitor. Found none.

Can you guys suggest anything else I can try to figure this thing out?

Comment: If a similar and near identical question is to be believed this is a driver issue

Comment: Are both monitors plugged into the GTS 240? What are their resolutions set to?

Comment: What exact version of video driver are you running for your GTS 240?

Comment: The driver is 9.18.13.4052 dated July 2, 2014. One display is 2560 X 1440. The other is 1920 X 1080. Both are plugged into the GTS 240.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to reinstall the drivers ? It seems like a driver issue to me.

Comment: Turns out that I had the current drivers, but a re-install of them seems to have helped. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help !